# Java WebClient both doOnError and doOnSuccess methods happen in a single request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

I'm using `WebClient` in a `spring boot` application and here is a part of my code:

```
    WebClient webClient = setApiKey(provider);
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri("sms")
            .body(Mono.just(jsonArray.toString()), String.class)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is4xxClientError(),
                    response -> Mono.error(new HttpClientErrorException(response.statusCode())))
            .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is5xxServerError(),
                    response -> Mono.error(new HttpServerErrorException(response.statusCode())))
            .bodyToMono(AdpBatchSmsResponseDto.class)
            .doOnSuccess(response -> logger.info("Successfully send SMS to : {} with {} ", clientId, provider.getSarShomare()))
            .doOnError(throwable -> logger.error("throws exception when send SMS to : {} with {} ", clientId, provider.getSarShomare(), throwable))
            .block();
```

in some cases, both `doOnError` and `doOnSuccess` methods happen and do the code which I want to each one do, nearly simultaneously. here is a picture from my log in `kibana`:

[image: kibana]

as it is highlighted, they have the same `traceId` and almost happen at the same time.
why they both happen? whether the call is successful or not, one of them might be called.

Comment: The `sarShomare` is different.

Comment: it was a good point. so why they have the same traceId and threadName?

Comment: How do you add trace ids? Thread name is likely to be shared as that’s really the point of reactive…

Comment: It also depends on how the request was sent into this app. Trace IDs can be shared in multiple requests if all of the requests were generated from the same "root", I believe. So if 1 requests comes into service A and service A splits calls to downstream services, it'll have the same trace ID.

Answer (score 0):

@majid-roustaei This looks like it's because you have 'swallowed' the exception in the 'doOnError' block, rather than rethrowing it. So, just like a catch block that logs an exception but does nothing else, the method will complete successfully.
To prevent successful completion you could just rethrow it by updating your `doOnError` lambda to this:

```java
   .doOnError(throwable -> { 
       logger.error("throws exception when send SMS to : {} with {} ", clientId, provider.getSarShomare(), throwable);
       throw throwable;
       })
```

That should stop your 'Successfully sent' message in the event of an exception.